# Cookies missing when server issues redirect using ClientSession

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, aiohttp

A good example would be a site login: POST user credentials and a session cookie would be set (Set-Cookie) with a 302, but after following the redirect neither ClientResponse.cookies, ClientResponse.history[-1].cookies, nor ClientSession.cookie_jar contain the session cookie.  Is this an error in aiohttp?  Note, I do see the cookie in ClientResponse.history[-1].headers.

Answer (score 1):

Seems as this is more an issue with SimpleCookie

https://bugs.python.org/issue23930
https://bugs.python.org/issue31456